# Are Windows GPOs encrypted?

Tags: windows, security, group-policy, encryption

We have a piece of COTS software that has a command line tool for server credential rotation. Instead of going to each machine to rotate the credentials with the tool, I would like to use GPO to run a script to do so. However, I would need to place the new credentials in the script, so I am wondering if the script files stored in the GPO are encrypted at rest. I have not found any authoritative documentation stating either way.

Comment: Don't do this. GPO's aren't encrypted.

Comment: @GregAskew, that's what I was afraid of. Any suggestions for alternatives?

Comment: This might a use case for LAPS - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/mt227395(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: A good, valid question that others may also ask. However, I echo Greg's recommendation against putting plain-text passwords in a GPO setting.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that they are not encrypted, I have not found a work around other path as of yet.

Comment: Hows about a managed Service Account? like https://www.advancedinstaller.com/install-service-under-managed-service-account.html - Once of the BASICS of MCSA, by the way - the answer is NO they are plain text. in case of using GPO/Script insteat the above solution

Answer (score 0):

No, GPOS are not encrypted. If you want an authoritative source: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/srd/2014/05/13/ms14-025-an-update-for-group-policy-preferences/

MS allowed passwords, but it later realized it was a security risk.

You can check for yourself: take a look at \\DOMAIN\SYSVOL and you'll see nothing is encrypted.

Comment: You need to set some credentials centrally, it seems. You are using a script. I assume a Startup script?

I'd consider storing a file with the password on a share, where only you and domain computer accounts would have access. Read the contents of the file and set the password to that. 

Or, even better, put the script on a server where only you and computer accounts have access to it, and run it directly from there.